# how to post only category name only not the value i selected for post

Tags: php, mysql

i want to post the value selected from the category table to software table by a php form but when i post the form it posting the id only instead of the value i selected

```
<form name="post" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="<?php echo $category"><?php
$categoryqu="SELECT * FROM categories";
$results=mysql_query($categoryqu);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
$id=$row['cid'];
$name=$row['name'];
echo"<option value='".$id."'>".$name."</option>";
}?> 

</option>
</select>

<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" type="text">
<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $link; ?>" type="text">
<input placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" type="text">
```

category table is 
[Category Table Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSCdq.png)
 and its posting only id instead of category names
 [here is the table posting the data from dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gKTN.png)
when i post the form it posting all are well but only the value of selected category is posting the value "id" but i want it post the selected value to the database where is the what is the error on this code

Comment: That is because within a HTML Select List the text between `<option >` and `</option>` acts as a User Friendly label for the key stored in the `value=""` bit. Your PHP code should then look the id up to retrieve the label if it needs to.

Comment: what is the right code for i am new in php

Answer (score 0):

But you use "**mcid**" to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

its just because in you php code

```
$id=$row['mcid'];
$name=$row['name'];
echo"<option value='".$id."'>".$name."</option>";
```

you are passing $id as a value so it will take its as a value of that tag,

simply just go with this

```
//$id=$row['mcid'];
$name=$row['name'];
echo"<option value='".$name."'>".$name."</option>";
```

Comment: its posting the value "0"

Answer (score 0):

Drop downs only post selected value not the title if you want to post both you can use some sort of delimiter.

Example:

```
 echo"<option value='".$id."#".$name."'>".$name."</option>";
```